# Understanding django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection is bad: nodename nor servname provided, or not known error

Tags: python, django, docker

I am attempting to create a Django website with a Postgress database. When I run python manage.py runserver command to start up the website I get the following error message.

Traceback Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 275, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 750, in connect
    raise last_ex.with_traceback(None)
psycopg.OperationalError: connection is bad: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 136, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 574, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 89, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 63, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 316, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 292, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 274, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 275, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 750, in connect
    raise last_ex.with_traceback(None)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection is bad: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

In order to solve this problem the first thing I attempted to do was check the Django documentation for the error message. In this [article] it references the error but does not go into much detail about how to solve it.
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/exceptions/#django.db.OperationalError)

I also looked at the Django documentation for connecting a Postgress database to Django but it did not answer my question. [Django Documentation on Postgress.] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes)

I also searched the error message in stack overflow and found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47612658/manage-py-test-error-in-django-involving-django-db-utils-operationalerror) and others but they did not solve my question.

I also checked the Docker forums, and the Django Forum for answers but there were no articles that answered my question. I signed up for a Docker course and watched the videos and did the official tutorials but I still don't understand why my database will not connect.

As for what I have attempted, I have attempted to change the name of the database and the user and password in django_project settings.py. I have attempted to change the PORT to 8000, and then changed it back.

As for troubleshooting the Dockerfile I have changed the volumes settings by establishing a path to reflect on what is stored on my computer. I changed the Postgress image setting with :latest to latest to try to tell docker to build with the most recent Postgress.

My question is what is the nodename or servname? Why is my Django project having trouble connecting to postgress?

django_project/settings.py

```
# django_project/settings.py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "postgres",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "postgres",
        "HOST": "db",  # set in docker-compose.yml
        "PORT": 5432,  # default postgres port
    }
}
```

I also looked at my Dockerfile and docker compose files.

Dockerfile

```
# Pull base image from docker hub. by not specifying a version I tell the hub to pull the latest file. 
FROM python
# Set environment variables
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# Set work directory
WORKDIR /Users/andrewstribling/Desktop/dev/code/ch4-bookstore
# Install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Copy project
COPY . .
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build: "."
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - /dev/code/ch4-bookstore/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Postgres container is not running with the minimum requirements. Up date your postgres container block and you should be good to go.  I suggest you read docker hub for the image your choosing https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres.

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    networks:
      - mynet
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
```